# convert files enconding recursively

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, file-encodings

Here I found a wonderful solution for recursively change the encoding of the files of one folder [Randomseed solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22921855/convert-files-encoding/44980033)

```
$path = realpath('C:\\your\\path');

$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path), 
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
);

foreach($iterator as $fileName => $file){
    if($file->isFile())
        file_put_contents(
            $fileName,
            iconv('ISO-8859-7', 'UTF-8', file_get_contents($fileName))
        );
}
```

But there is a problem. Every file is changed, even images, and they are not shown later. 
How to edit this for changing only `.php` files for example?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to loop over .php files, Simply look at the extension of the file.

```
    foreach($iterator as $fileName => $file){
    if($file->isFile() && $file->getExtension() == "php")
        file_put_contents(
            $fileName,
            iconv('ISO-8859-7', 'UTF-8', file_get_contents($fileName))
        );
   }
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you very much.